# Can I use Frame in iPad,not AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, frame

As title saying,can I use frame to make iPad app?I think autolayout is fantastic,but as a temporarily plan,if I keep use frame in my project,it will look normal in ipad,now my project in ipad look like in 4s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use frames if you want to. If you want your interface to work on different sizes of screen, you can use autoresizing instead of autolayout. Or you can test on just one type of device while developing, and thus postpone worrying about the screen size issue. But be sure to address the matter somehow before shipping! Your app will not look good on different iPad models unless you do.

Comment: If I use frames,the interface looks normal?I mean,it will not seems like in 4s.

Comment: If you design in code, or if you design in the storyboard on an iPad-sized view controller view, it will look correct in the Simulator for the same iPad. But if you design in the storyboard for an iPhone, then if you use frames and you do not use autoresizing or autolayout, it will look _terrible_ on the iPad or any other device.

Comment: OK,Thank you very much.I get what I want from you,so sweet.